# Splitting an Array in C

Tags: c, arrays, split

Suppose I have an array and I want to remove elements from certain ranges of indices.

If I know ahead of time the size of the array, the size of every element in the array, and what ranges of indices I want to remove is there any way I can avoid copying over a new array?

Comment: Could you instead just not "use" the parts of the array you wish to exclude? (I'm not sure what that means in the context of your application.)

Comment: you don't need a new array,  but you can copy within your current array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't want to use a new array for copying , you can think of doing this in the same array itself , here is what I have :

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>
int main()
{
  char str[] = "hello world";
  int i , strt , end , j;

  setbuf ( stdout , NULL );

  printf ("enter the start and end points of the range of the array to remove:\n");
  scanf ("%d%d", &strt , &end);
  int len = strlen (str);
  for ( i = end; i >= strt ;i--)
    {
      str[i-1] = str[i];
      for ( j = i+1; j <= len ; j++)
        {
        str[j-1] = str[j];
        }
      len--;
    }

  printf ("%s" , str);
  return 0;
}
```

While this code is for **character arrays**, you can also use the algorithm for **integer arrays** with slight modifications (**do it as exercise** ).

NOTE:- This method is not very efficient though , as you can see the exponential increase in the complexity , so my advice would be just to use the **copying over new array method** .

Answer (score 1):

Hello you could do something like that.

```
int main(int ac, char **av)
{
    char  *str;
    int   i;

    i = 0;
    str = strdup("Hello World");
    while(str[i])
    {
        if(i == 6) // 6 = W the range of the array you want to remove
        str[i] = '\0';
        i++;
    }
    printf("%s\n", str);
}
```

The output will be "Hello" instead of "Hello World".