# Cutting Out a Section of a void* array in C

Tags: c, arrays, slice

Say I have a void* array 32 bytes long and I want to remove the data from byte 8 to byte 16.
Is it possible to "cut out" these bytes somehow?

Comment: You mean copy bytes 17..31 forward 8 bytes? Sure. What should go at the end?

Comment: "cut out" as in shifting the end of the array towards the start of the array?

Comment: How is this different from your other question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17645417/splitting-an-array-in-c

Comment: There I wanted to try and remove certain indicies. Here I'm trying to manipulate the data directly byte by byte (by copying it over).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since an array in C is a contiguous region of memory, you cannot "cut out" its parts without making a copy.

Here is how to do it with [`memcpy`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/memcpy.html):

```
char copy[16];
char *ptr = voidPtr;
memcpy(copy, ptr, 8);      // Copy bytes 0..7
memcpy(copy+8, ptr+16, 8); // Copy bytes 16..31
```

Comment: Making a copy is fine. Could you perhaps give me a small code example?

Answer (score 0):

You can just convert to `char *` and zero out indices 7-15.